# What does "Are you sometimes swinging about the U.S?" mean?

Tags: meaning

In a conversation with a U.S colleague, he asked me if I'm sometimes swinging about the U.S (exact quote is in the title). What is the meaning of swinging in this context ?

Comment: 'traveling through'

Comment: If you were in a foreign country when he asked you this, might he have asked if you were swinging through? While *swinging through* is an idiom for *'visiting'*, *swinging about* is not.

Comment: I was in my home country in Europe. There was also no doubt about the fact that there is no imminent trip planned to the U.S.

Comment: Could it mean something like "Thinking about with nostalgia" ?

Comment: No, it really could not.

Comment: Unless you or the colleague has a proclivity for group sex, it's likely to mean 'traveling through'.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably an unusual version of the idiom medica cites, *swinging through*. It might be a slip of the tongue, or it might be a deliberate extension; *swinging through* occasionally shows up as *swinging **around***, as in this from a Reddit thread for travelers looking for a place to stay:

> If any of ya'll southern ameristralians ever swing around central Illinois, I'm a student in Champaign IL, and I have a couch open to any of you, just send me a PM.

Or this from a gunowners' forum:

> If you ever swing around the King of Prussia area, I'll be more than happy to have you come out with me to take some of his triggers for a spin.

It’s not a big step from *swinging around* to *swinging about*, as in *traveling about* a country.

Answer (score 0):

To *swing by* a place means to visit that place, usually in a casual manner, perhaps on your way to somewhere else.

From the context, I'd say *swinging about* is a variation on that. Perhaps because the U.S. is not a particular place, but a collection of places in the mind of the speaker.